# Ubuntu Touch SDK problems

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, qt-creator, qml

I have installed the Ubuntu touch SDK the way it is advised on the Ubuntu dev website (with  `sudo apt-get install ubuntu`). I'm using Ubuntu  13.04.

The problems/symptoms are the following :

1. When I run a new QML project, I've got QT creator saying : "`QQmlComponent: Component is not ready`"
2. When I create a new project and run it using the "Tabbed UI" preset, I can't swipe between tabs with a left to right or right to left gesture.
3. When I create a new Ubuntu Touch QML project, I can't use QT Designer. QT Designer's main frame remains empty. However, if I start a new QT Quick project, then I can use QT Designer.

I don't now if those problems are linked, the most important one being not able to use QT Designer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ask one single question per post, which makes it easier to answer. In any case:

1. This is due to [bug 1154980](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1154980)
2. This might be related to [bug 1166709](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1166709)
3. Currently Ubuntu SDK components are not supported in the designer, but supporting them is on the roadmap

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I'm sorry,I feared these issues were linked (for e.g caused by a bad SDK installation) that's why I posted them together.